# Adding number to fetched array with php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have some problem with adding numbering to the fetched array on the parsed xml output. I got a code from a website located here http://www.mightywebdeveloper.com/coding/mysql-to-xml-php/

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$oid= $_GET['oid'];

//database configuration
$config['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$config['mysql_user'] = "thisisuser";
$config['mysql_pass'] = "thisispass";
$config['db_name']    = "mydb";
$config['table_name'] = "mail";

//connect to host
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
//select database
@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");

$xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root_element = $config['table_name']."s"; //fruits
$xml         .= "<$root_element>";

//select all items in table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE oid='".$oid."' ORDER BY id ";

//SELECT * FROM ".$config['table_name'];

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $xml .= "<".$config['table_name'].">";

      //loop through each key,value pair in row
      foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
      {
         //$key holds the table column name
         $xml .= "<$key>";

         //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
         $xml .= "$value";

         //and close the element
         $xml .= "</$key>";
      }

      $xml.="</".$config['table_name'].">";
   }
}

//close the root element
$xml .= "</$root_element>";

//send the xml header to the browser
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

//output the XML data
echo $xml;

?>
```

It work just fine after a few edit and the output goes like this.

```
<mails>
    <mail>
        <id>1011</id>
        <oid>1</oid>
        <from>Test User</from>
        <content>This is a test mail.</content>
    </mail>
        <mail>
        <id>101222</id>
        <oid>1</oid>
        <from>Test User</from>
        <content>This is a test mail.</content>
    </mail>
</mails>
```

My problem is I would like to display the fetched array number and automaticaly increase the number next to the mail tag similar to something like

```
<mails>
    <mail  id="1"> <-fetched array number? I dont know how to add this.
        <id>101221</id>
        <oid>1</oid>
        <from>Test User</from>
        <content>This is a test mail.</content>
    </mail>
        <mail  id="2">
        <id>101222</id>
        <oid>1</oid>
        <from>Test User</from>
        <content>This is a test mail.</content>
    </mail>
</mails>
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = 1;   // write this before loop
```

then instead of `$xml .= "<$key>";`

```
$xml .= ($key == 'mail' ? "<$key id=\"".$mail++."\">" : "<$key>");
```

Comment: where do I write the $mail =1;

Comment: for example, before this `if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)`

Comment: Still the same result no changes

Comment: such tag    `<mail>` ?

Comment: the result still like this`<mail>
<id>1111112</id>
<oid>1</oid>
<from>Test User</from>
<content>This is a test mail.</content>
</mail>
<mail>...</mail>`

Comment: did you chang the second line?

Comment: Yea I changed to this `$xml .= ($key == 'mail' ? "<$key $id=".$mail++.">" : "<$key>");`

Comment: By the way there is typo there - must be `"<$key id="`